# Can't disable same origin policy on nginx

Tags: ajax, nginx, same-origin-policy

I need to disable the same origin policy on the server. Just as a background: I have verified that everything is working by starting chrome with the disable web security flag. Everything works as expected.

Here's what I have done on the nginx side:

```
upstream phpfcgi {
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; #for PHP-FPM running on UNIX socket
}

server {
listen 80;

root /var/www/yammi2;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
server_name myserver.ch;

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Content-Type,accept,x-wsse,origin';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';

# strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

location / {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;

}
```

}

When I then do curl call: curl -I myserver.ch, I get the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=gvcl3v533ib91l2c6v888gl9d3; path=/
cache-control: no-cache
date: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 07:01:18 GMT
location: http://myserver.ch/admin/restaurant
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,accept,x-wsse,origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
```

so at least it seems that the headers are set correctly, yet the result when I make the ajax call:

```
OPTIONS http://myserver.ch/api/v1/restaurant/closest?max=50&lat=47&lon=8 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.0.3.js:7845
OPTIONS http://myserver.ch/api/v1/restaurant/closest?max=50&lat=47&lon=8 Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery-2.0.3.js:7845
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver.ch/api/v1/restaurant/closest?max=50&lat=47&lon=8. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. overview.html:1
```

I'm a bit confused by the "Internal Server Error", but I figured since it works with the flag, this has to be something to do with same origin.

The server application is a symphony app. I hope I haven't missed anything. Any idea how to fix this? Or even how to debug it?

Maybe one last snipped, here is how I make the call (again, shouldn't be the issue, because with the disable security flag it works as expected):

```
$.ajax({
          url: url,
          headers: {"x-wsse": getWsseHeader()},
          beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("x-wsse", getWsseHeader());
          },
          success: function() {

          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.statusText);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Try to call with curl STATIC file and check if this work. If you get Internal Error - problem in server config in other result - with your script. This is your start point.

Comment: good hint. So pointing the request to a static file works as expected, but then as soon as I add the additional x-wsse headers it doesn't work anymore (even with the static file). When I though submit the same request via Postman (Rest client), it works just fine. More hints?

Comment: Did some tweaking. I can now send the preflight OPTIONS call, returns succesfully, but as soons as I make the GET call the request get's cancelled?! No response, nothing on the server either.

Answer (score 4):

Change this line

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

as

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '';
```